# How to write update batch sql by using array

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have an array

```
[['Tom', 1], ['Jerry', 2], ['Jessica', 3]]
```

I have discovered following syntax to insert a bunch of rows:

```
insert into tbl (col2,col1) values ?
```

So, I tried to use syntax for update

```
update tbl set col1=?, col3=NOW() where col1=?
```

But it failed :

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

Could update sql use such syntax for batch action?

P.S. The node code below is for your information

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
let db = require('../configs/db');
let pool = mysql.createPool(db);

connPool (sql, val, cb) {  //function name
    pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
      if(err){
        console.log('Connection Error:' + err);
      }else{
        console.log('allConnections:' + pool._allConnections.length);
        let q = conn.query(sql, val, (err, rows,fields) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Query:' + sql + ' error:' + err);
             }
            cb(err, rows, fields);
            conn.release();
        });
      }
    });
},

...
let func = require('../sql/func');
let arr = [['Tom', 1], ['Jerry', 2], ['Jessica', 3]];
sql =  'update tbl set col1=?, col3=NOW() where col1=?';

func.connPool(sql, arr , (err,rows,fields) => {
  if(err==null){
     res.json({code: 200, msg: 'success'});
  } else {
     res.json({code: 400, msg: 'failed'+err});
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you post the node code that goes along with this question? There's not enough information here to try to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @JoshuaTerrillJos updated。 Anyway, I used delete and insert solution, but I'm still wondering whether batch update has this kind of syntax